# Calculating two parameters for a two variable equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$$y=1-\frac{k}{x^b}, k>0$$

When $(x=4,y=0)$ and $(x=200, y=0.9)$. How do I solve this equation elegantly?
When I try to do it, it always ends up being $b=0$ and $k=1$.

My end goal is, to create a function which has lim y=0 and lim x=1 (that I can control two points on the graph) which looks like this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 = 1-\dfrac{k}{4^b} \Longrightarrow k=4^b$

$0.9 = 1-\dfrac{k}{200^b} \Longrightarrow \left(\dfrac{4}{200}\right)^b = 0.1$

Taking the natural log of both sides gives:

$b\ln 0.02 = \ln 0.1$

$b = \dfrac{\ln 0.1}{\ln 0.02}$

Then, plugging that in, you have $k = 4^{\ln 0.1/\ln 0.02}$

Answer (score 2):

Plugging both points in gives you
$$
0=1-\frac{k}{4^b} \\
0.9=1-\frac{k}{200^b}
$$
Solving for $k$ gives
$$
k = 4^b = 0.1 \cdot 200^b
$$
So you have
$$
10 = 50^b 
$$
or $b = \log 10 / \log 50 \simeq 0.588$ and $
k = 4^b \simeq 2.261 $. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

From the first condition we get
$$4^b=k$$
plugging this in the other equation we get
$$\frac{9}{10}=1-(\frac{4}{200})^b$$
From here you will get #b#-